# Live server isn't running scripts

Tags: javascript, html, npm-live-server

I'm on chrome on a Mac, and the index file runs but the script doesn't change anything. I tried just removing paragraphs and that doesn't work either. I tried hard refreshing and running from the Live extension.

This is the code from Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
    <head>
        <h1> I've a lot of things to do today.</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> 1. Get the litter & Wet Food.</p>
        <p> 2. Clean the Room.</p>
        <p> 3. Go out with the girlfriend.</p>
        <p> 4. Teach Rishabh.</p>
        <p> 5. Watch a show.</p>
        <p> 6. DON'T GET ANYMORE NFTS SER.</p>
        <script scr="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and scripts.js

```
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('p')
ps.forEach(function(p){
    p.remove()
})
```

The script isn't called at all because even a simple console.log statement in the scripts.js file won't run. No errors either :/

Thanks a lot for the help. I'm super new and this has been kinda frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is perfectly Fine, but I would say you to not to use the `h1` in the `head` tag.

- The problem with the snippet provided is that there is a typo in the source definition of the script!
- Use the correct definition for the  source **`src`** in place of the `scr`.

```js
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yup! Legit feel like an idiot rn ahaha. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't write `h1` like this in `head`, `head` is used for meta-data, link, and other things to configure html page before loading. If you want, you can set a `title` in head to replace your `h1` or move your `h1` in your `body`. Rest of your content should be in `body`.

**Edit :** And you have a spell error, it's `src` not "scr" for import your script !

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>To Do Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>I've a lot of things to do today.</h1>
    <p>1. Get the litter & Wet Food.</p>
    <p>2. Clean the Room.</p>
    <p>3. Go out with the girlfriend.</p>
    <p>4. Teach Rishabh.</p>
    <p>5. Watch a show.</p>
    <p>6. DON'T GET ANYMORE NFTS SER.</p>
    <script src="./scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You may run a little `console.log()` for ensure your import is fine, before working on script like this, if the log, at top of the js file doesn't not appear in your console browser, the script is probably not imported.

```js
console.log("test");

let ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
ps.forEach(function (p) {
  p.remove();
});
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I TOTALLY MISSED THAT AND WAS STUCK SINCE YESTERDAY. I APPRECIATE IT! 

It was the src.

Comment: Spell error is common !

Answer (score 0):

Correct your spelling. `scr` should be `src`.